# Dropdownlist via WebService problems with definitions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to make my Dropdownlist populated via a WebServices
I got some errors.

> cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Get_Car> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Car>'.

CarServices.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

public class CarService : ICarService
{
public List<Car> GetCars()

    {
        using (CarDataContext db = new CarDataContext())
        {
            return (from car in db.Cars
                select new Get_Car()
                {
                    Id = car.Id,
                    Car_name = car.Car_name
                }).ToList();              <---- got an error here
        }
    }
}
```

ICarService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;


[ServiceContract]
public interface ICarService
{
[OperationContract]
List<Car> GetCars();
}
```

Car.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Get_Car
{
private int id;
    private string car_name;

    public Get_Car()
{

    }

    public int Id { get { return this.id; } set { this.id = value; } }
    public string Car_name { get { return this.car_name; } set {this.car_name = value;}}

}
```

Apointement.aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM 
    [Car]" TableName="Cars"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<div id="template">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="titletext">
                 Apointement
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server"></asp:LinqDataSource>

        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"    
        ContextTypeName="ApointementDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
        EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Apointement" 
             Where="IsAvailable = True && dateTrial >= DateTime.Now && 
                    carsTrial = @carsTrial"> 

            <WhereParameters>
               <asp:ControlParameter 
                   Name="carsTrial" 
                   ControlID="DropDownList1" 
                   PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                   DefaultValue="Ferrari458italia2011"
                   Type="String" />
             </WhereParameters>

        </asp:LinqDataSource>

        <div class="center">

            <asp:Label ID="lblCarTrial" runat="server" Text="Choose a car to try"> </asp:Label>

           <div class="value-right"> 
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="180px" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  DataTextField="Car_name" DataSourceID ="Id" >


               </asp:DropDownList>
```

Apointement.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Apointement : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "";

        DropDownList1.DataSource = GetCars();
        DropDownList1.DataBind();


    private void ListCars()
    {
        using (CarDataContext db = new CarDataContext())
        {
            var carItems = from car in db.Cars select car;

            DropDownList1.DataSource = carItems;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        };
    }

    private List<CarService.**Car**> GetCars()
    {
        CarService.**CarService** client = new CareService.**CarService**();

        CarService.**car[]** cars = client.GetCars();

       return cars.ToList();
 }                             *<=== all the fields in bold got errors.  
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate as I am new to C#. I will like more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I wasn't able to do an Update Web/Service References.  Someone suggest to close everything from Visual Studio and open the Web site again.  Then I was able to perform the Update Web/Service Reference.

the final solution looks like this:

CarService.cs

```
public class CarService : ICarService
{
    public List<Car>  CareDetail()  
    {
        using (CarDataContext db = new CarDataContext())
        {
            return db.Cars.ToList();
}}}
```

ICarService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICarService
{
[OperationContract]
List<Car> CarDetail();
}
```

code behind.aspx.cs

```
private List<CarServiceReference.Car> CarDetail()
{
    CarServiceReference.CarServiceClient client = new CarServiceReference.CareServiceClient();

    CarServiceReference.Car[] cars = client.CarDetail();

    return cars.ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a `List<Get_Car>` where you should be returning a `List<Car>`, and since `Get_Car` does appear to inherit from `Car`, you can't do that, the two types are not the same and not interchangeable.

Comment: can you elaborate as I am new to C#. I will like more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to rename your class from Get_Car to Car in Car.cs:

This:

```
public class Get_Car
```

To this:

```
public class Car
```

Also you will need to rename your constructor the same too.

Comment: I got errors in CarService.cs, the system is complaining about The call is ambigous between the following method or properties Car.Car() and Car.Car()

Comment: You must have two classes named Car.Car, I'm guessing that one is from the EntityFramework. I would rename your Car.cs to CarDto.cs to avoid this.

Comment: I rename it to CarDetail.  The only errors left now is in the Apointement.aspx.cs       I got problem building this part.                                     private List<CarService.Car> CarDetail()   
    {
        CarService.CarService client = new CarService.CarService();
        CarService.car[] cars = client.CarDetail();

        return car.ToList();

Comment: If I go after the CarService. I don't see any object, I just see the Equals and ReferenceEquals so My object seems to be not build properly

Comment: Make sure that you rename your service interface to match the changes, that could be your error.

Comment: I have CarDetail.cs and I should also rename the CarService.cs to CarDetailService.cs ?

Comment: I go after the private List<CarService.  and here I don't see anything listed after the dot

Comment: You don't want a List<CarService>, you should only have one. I would make sure your method in CarService is public and also defined in the Interface too.

Comment: Make sure you are updating the service reference too in your web app, it could be caching the old one.

Comment: We are close to fix it.                                         private List<CarServiceReference.CarServiceClient> CarDetail()
    {
        VoitureServiceReference.VoitureServiceClient client = new VoitureServiceReference.VoitureServiceClient();

        CarServiceReference.CarServiceClient[] car = client.      <** missing this part>  .VoitureDetail();

        return cars.ToList();       I am missing the part after the client.   I think it should be CarDetail() but no definition of CarDetail in Client

Comment: When you add a service reference, you can change the return type to be Generic lists, by default they're arrays. To change that you can right click select update service and you will see the options.

Comment: Are you sure we can do this?  When I am in VS i got this error Failed to update Service Reference. Error Unable to connect to the configurated dev. Web Server  (the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: Finally I got the Update Web/Service working after closing Visual Studio and re-open it.  The only error left is the following   Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'CarServiceReference.Car[]' to 'CarServiceReference.CarServiceClient[]' C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Apointement\CarDealer\pages\Apointement.aspx.cs 191 67       VoitureServiceReference.VoitureServiceClient client = new VoitureServiceReference.VoitureServiceClient();

CarServiceReference.CarServiceClient[] cars = client.CarDetail();
The error is on the CarDetail().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45675/discussion-between-hutchonoid-and-user3127986)